# Java: Problem With Greek File Names (non-latin file names)

Tags: java, file, filesystems

Using Java:
 I am reading a directory containing files with Greek Names. But when i output a String containing a file name i get this '???????.something'.

Is it because i am running the java app. through the console?

Is there a way to get non-latin file names read correctly?

Thanks,

Comment: Posting some code may get you better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could well be reading in the file names correctly; the most likely explanation is that your console can't render non-Latin characters.

For example, the following program is supposed to print out the first three letters of the Greek alphabet:

```
public class AlphaBetaGamma
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String abc = "\u03b1\u03b2\u03b3";
        System.out.println(abc);
    }
}
```

It prints out "???" on my Console, because it's not capable of rendering the Greek characters.

Answer (score 1):

change your console to use utf-8 as char encoding - that should fix that issue

Comment: This will only work if the default platform encoding is UTF-8. So, it might work on Ubuntu, but won't work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what simonn wrote, it's worth writing out the Unicode code points with something like this:

```
public static void dumpString(String text)
{
    for (int i=0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        System.out.printf("%c U+%04x", c, (int) c);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You can then look at the [Unicode web site](http://unicode.org) to find out what those characters *really* mean. (The [Code Charts page](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) is very handy.)